# Python UDP Server Not Receiving Data

Tags: python, sockets, proxy, udp

I have UDP ethernet traffic that I want to receive on a machine (192.168.2.2:7800) (coming from a separate machine (192.168.2.12)).

I can see the data is flowing on the receive machine by doing a tcp dump:

```
tcpdump -n -i enp5s0f1 udp port 7800
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on enp5s0f1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
19:04:13.160763 IP 192.168.2.12.ovbus > 192.168.2.2.asr: UDP, length 1052
19:04:13.170854 IP 192.168.2.12.ovbus > 192.168.2.2.asr: UDP, length 1052
```

I have tried setting up a python UDP server with the IP of 192.168.2.2 and a port of 7800 using the following code which I got from Radoslaw Matusiak here (https://github.com/rsc-dev/pyproxy/blob/master/code/pyproxy.py):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

__author__      = 'Radoslaw Matusiak'
__copyright__   = 'Copyright (c) 2016 Radoslaw Matusiak'
__license__     = 'MIT'
__version__     = '0.1'


"""
TCP/UDP proxy.
"""

import argparse
import signal
import logging
import select
import socket


FORMAT = '%(asctime)-15s %(levelname)-10s %(message)s'
logging.basicConfig(format=FORMAT)
LOGGER = logging.getLogger()

LOCAL_DATA_HANDLER = lambda x:x
REMOTE_DATA_HANDLER = lambda x:x

BUFFER_SIZE = 2 ** 10  # 1024. Keep buffer size as power of 2.


def udp_proxy(src, dst):
    """Run UDP proxy.
    
    Arguments:
    src -- Source IP address and port string. I.e.: '127.0.0.1:8000'
    dst -- Destination IP address and port. I.e.: '127.0.0.1:8888'
    """
    LOGGER.debug('Starting UDP proxy...')
    LOGGER.debug('Src: {}'.format(src))
    LOGGER.debug('Dst: {}'.format(dst))
    
    proxy_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    proxy_socket.bind(ip_to_tuple(src))
    
    client_address = None
    server_address = ip_to_tuple(dst)
    
    LOGGER.debug('Looping proxy (press Ctrl-Break to stop)...')
    while True:
        data, address = proxy_socket.recvfrom(BUFFER_SIZE)
        LOGGER.debug('Data Received')
        
        if client_address == None:
            client_address = address

        if address == client_address:
            data = LOCAL_DATA_HANDLER(data)
            proxy_socket.sendto(data, server_address)
        elif address == server_address:
            data = REMOTE_DATA_HANDLER(data)
            proxy_socket.sendto(data, client_address)
            client_address = None
        else:
            LOGGER.warning('Unknown address: {}'.format(str(address)))
# end-of-function udp_proxy    
    
    
def tcp_proxy(src, dst):
    """Run TCP proxy.
    
    Arguments:
    src -- Source IP address and port string. I.e.: '127.0.0.1:8000'
    dst -- Destination IP address and port. I.e.: '127.0.0.1:8888'
    """
    LOGGER.debug('Starting TCP proxy...')
    LOGGER.debug('Src: {}'.format(src))
    LOGGER.debug('Dst: {}'.format(dst))
    
    sockets = []
    
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind(ip_to_tuple(src))
    s.listen(1)

    s_src, _ = s.accept()

    s_dst = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s_dst.connect(ip_to_tuple(dst)) 
    
    sockets.append(s_src)
    sockets.append(s_dst)
    
    while True:
        s_read, _, _ = select.select(sockets, [], [])
        
        for s in s_read:
            data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
        
            if s == s_src:
                d = LOCAL_DATA_HANDLER(data)
                s_dst.sendall(d)
            elif s == s_dst:
                d = REMOTE_DATA_HANDLER(data)
                s_src.sendall(d)
# end-of-function tcp_proxy    


def ip_to_tuple(ip):
    """Parse IP string and return (ip, port) tuple.
    
    Arguments:
    ip -- IP address:port string. I.e.: '127.0.0.1:8000'.
    """
    ip, port = ip.split(':')
    return (ip, int(port))
# end-of-function ip_to_tuple


def main():
    """Main method."""
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='TCP/UPD proxy.')
    
    # TCP UPD groups
    proto_group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
    proto_group.add_argument('--tcp', action='store_true', help='TCP proxy')
    proto_group.add_argument('--udp', action='store_true', help='UDP proxy')
    
    parser.add_argument('-s', '--src', required=True, help='Source IP and port, i.e.: 127.0.0.1:8000')
    parser.add_argument('-d', '--dst', required=True, help='Destination IP and port, i.e.: 127.0.0.1:8888')
    
    output_group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
    output_group.add_argument('-q', '--quiet', action='store_true', help='Be quiet')
    output_group.add_argument('-v', '--verbose', action='store_true', help='Be loud')
    
    args = parser.parse_args()
    
    if args.quiet:
        LOGGER.setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
    if args.verbose:
        LOGGER.setLevel(logging.NOTSET)
    
    if args.udp:
        udp_proxy(args.src, args.dst)
    elif args.tcp:
        tcp_proxy(args.src, args.dst)
# end-of-function main    


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

However, when I run the command testpyProxy.py --udp -d 192.168.2.13:7800 -s 192.168.2.2:7800 I never get a receive:

```
2009-01-23 19:11:38,786 DEBUG      BUFFER SIZE: 32768
2009-01-23 19:11:38,786 DEBUG      Starting UDP proxy...
2009-01-23 19:11:38,786 DEBUG      Src: 192.168.2.2:7800
2009-01-23 19:11:38,786 DEBUG      Dst: 192.168.2.12:7800
2009-01-23 19:11:38,787 DEBUG      Looping proxy (press Ctrl-Break to stop)...
```

This python proxy is running on a Centos 7 (192.168.2.2) machine with the ethernet port connection stats from ifconfig:

```
enp5s0f1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 9000
        inet 192.168.2.2  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.2.255
        inet6 fe80::21b:acff:fe02:af29  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:1b:ac:02:af:29  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 206136919  bytes 494683048962 (460.7 GiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 50795  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1018446  bytes 564508158 (538.3 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

I have simplified the code that I am running thanks to a suggestion from tdelaney.
On the server side (192.168.2.2 machine) I am running the following code:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3
import socket
BUFFER_SIZE = 2 ** 9  # 1024. Keep buffer size as power of 2.
proxy_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
proxy_socket.bind(("192.168.2.2", 7900))
while True:
    data, address = proxy_socket.recvfrom(BUFFER_SIZE)
    print('received')
```

On the client side (from 192.168.2.12 machine) I am running this code:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3
import socket
msgFromClient       = "Hello UDP Server"
bytesToSend         = str.encode(msgFromClient)
serverAddressPort   = ("192.168.2.2", 7900)
bufferSize          = 1024
# Create a UDP socket at client side
UDPClientSocket = socket.socket(family=socket.AF_INET, type=socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
# Send to server using created UDP socket
UDPClientSocket.sendto(bytesToSend, serverAddressPort)
print('sent')
```

I still have the same result as before. No received data even though I have evidence (through tcp dump) that the data was sent.

**SOLUTION:**
Looks like there was a firewall issue preventing the port from being monitored. The following were the commands that I took to add the port:

```
--Adds the port to the firewall
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=7800/udp
--restart the firewall service for the port to take effect
systemctl restart firewalld
```

Comment: That's a pretty large chunk of code. I think the first step is to copy it to a test file and pull out everything but the dgram receive code. Hard code everything, make it self contained. Maybe a second script that just does send. Again all hard coded addresses. That will give the simplest example and we can work on that.

Comment: @tdelaney I have simplified the scenario but unfortunately got the same result.

Comment: The code should work... you may have some sort of a split horizons network problem where the two machines don't see each other (try ping at the command prompt or other way to test connection). It may be a firewall thing on the server side. If its Windows for instance, you may need to open that port or give python the right to read that port. If these are on different subnets, you'd need to worry about the router/bridge also.

Comment: @tdelaney Looks like it was a firewall issue. After adding the port to the firewall (on the server side) it now receives data. Thanks for your help. I really appreciate it! I will update my question with the solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**
Looks like there was a firewall issue preventing the port from being monitored. The following were the commands that I took to add the port:

```
--Adds the port to the firewall
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=7800/udp
--restart the firewall service for the port to take effect
systemctl restart firewalld
```